# How to change items in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

How can I change view controller in `UITabBarController`. `UITabBarController` is created from `Storyboard`. I.e. want to remove last item. Enable to NO `UITabBarItem` will only disable button, but not hide it.

[image]

Comment: What u wanna do remove the bar button item from tab bar or load different VC when a bar button item pressed ??

Comment: @/jános : Up voted and favorited ur question will keep an eye on this :) Sounds very interesting

Comment: @SandeepBhandari the baritem is the property of view controller only. so removing view controllers remove the baritem as well

Comment: @jános : My apologies looks like setting the ViewControllers Array back after deleting the VC from existing array does remove item from tab bar So the below posted answer is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to get viewcontrollers for an array and change the array. After modification assign back to UITabBarController

```
    NSMutableArray *viewCotrollers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[tbc viewControllers]];
    [viewCotrollers removeLastObject];
    [tbc setViewControllers:viewCotrollers animated:YES];
```

To get the TabBarController you can use following code

```
    UITabBarController *tbc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarController"];
```

Todo this you need to set identifier for your UITabBarController on storyboard

Comment: +1. I din know setting the ViewControllers array of UITabBarController will reset its tab bar items :) Nice one hence +1. Learnt something new